# Starting and Stopping a Process On A Set Interval in Windows

Tags: windows-7

I have an exe, lets call it MyProgram, that I run from the command line with arguments, like so:

> MyProgram.exe -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD

My problem is, that I need to run this program, let it run for 30 minutes, then terminate the program, do nothing for one minute, and the repeat this process indefinitely. I have no idea were to even start.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you should use the `task scheduler` to do that...
Press the Windows key, type "task" (dépending on your local though. If your Windows is french, it's called "Planificateur de tâches", and so on...) and run it.

Then select "Create a task", and fill in the following informations :

- Name: A name for your task
- Description : Explain what it does and when it's supposed to run
- (in "Trigger" tab) : Click "New..." then "Each day", and "Repeat the task every '31 minutes'" in the advanced parameters (**Important note :** The field seems to be a dropdown box, but you can type in your own value !)
- Also be sure to click "Stop the task if it's running more than 30 minutes"

Your task will be automatically be run the way you asked.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to have worked. I would up mod your post but I lack the rep.

Comment: I think it's called Task Scheduler.

Comment: You may be right. I must admit I translated my french version... :) Corrected